# Restore InnoDB from .frm files

Tags: mysql, innodb

My database crashed and my PC and I now only have the `.frm` and `.ibd` files left.

Is there any way to restore my database?

Comment: Questions: 1) Windows or Linux ??? 2) Do you have the `ibdata1` file ??? 3) Do you have the `my.ini` or `my.cnf` ???

Comment: Read this blog which contains all the steps for restoring the database: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/163100-how-to-backup-and-restore-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Two potential workarounds:

1. Simulate the internal InnoDB table counter. That is, create work tables (with innodb_file_per_table enabled) until you have the internal pointer of table id equal to (1 – id_of_ibd_table_you_need_to_restore).
2. Manually hex edit the .ibd file, changing the table id.

See [Recovering an InnoDB table from only an .ibd file](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28) for the full explanation and the detailed steps involved.